# insert an image into a frame x y coordinates

Tags: scheme, racket, mit-scheme

Hi I would like to know how to insert an image into a window but with coordinates.

```
(define ventana (new frame%
                   [label "Ba"]
                   [width 1100]
                   [height 600]))


(define tablero-panel (new horizontal-panel%
                             (parent ventana)
                             ;(label "Group Box Panel")
                             (alignment   '(left top))
                             (min-width 500)
                             (min-height 500)
                             (stretchable-width #f)
                             (stretchable-height #f)
                             ;(spacing 100)
                             ;(vert-margin 100)
                             ;(horiz-margin 500)
                            ; (border 50)

                             )
  )
```

I need that image is in the window frame but in certain coordinates

to insert I found on this page but I can not coordinatesthey can be in xy

[bitmap in dr racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355251/bitmap-in-dr-racket)

Comment: The above code is syntactically incorrect.  Have you tried it yet?

Comment: the truth is that I have this:

It is edited in the main message

A public user how through message% but I can not set that coordinates of the window displaying the image

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is against the grain of the gui library.  The design of the GUI library is that you give control of layout mostly to it, rather than try to control it yourself.  See [Geometry Management](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html#%28part._containeroverview%29).

If you want more control over where things are drawn, you can create a frame with a single [`canvas%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/canvas_.html) instance, and within that, draw whatever you want.  You can use the [draw-bitmap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=dc#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket/draw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._draw-bitmap%29%29) of the drawing context (the `dc`) of your canvas.

For example:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require net/url)


(define f (new frame% 
               [label "Test"]
               [width 500]
               [height 500]))

(define bm (make-object bitmap% (get-pure-port
                                 (string->url "http://racket-lang.org/logo.png"))))

(define pos 0)

(define mycanvas%
  (class canvas%
    (super-new)
    (inherit get-dc)
    (define/override (on-paint)
      (let ([my-dc (get-dc)])
        (send my-dc draw-bitmap bm pos pos)))))

(define c (new mycanvas% [parent f]))

(send f show #t)

(void
 (thread (lambda ()
           (let loop ()
             (set! pos (add1 pos))
             (send c refresh)
             (sleep 1/20)
             (loop)))))
```