# How to use GraphViz and Racket

Tags: racket, graphviz, pict

Is it possible to use the graphviz module to draw graphs in a racket frame (GUI)?
If it's possible, would anyone a tutorial that shows how to use?
Thank's

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do:

- generate a dot-file (the Graphviz format) from the graph
- use `system` to run grapviz on the file producing a png file
- display the png in a racket frame

For actual code see: https://github.com/wangkuiyi/graphviz-server

Note that Stephen Chang's graph library has support for generating dot-files: http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/graph/index.html#%28part._.Graphviz%29

Update:

In order to make a graph editor you can save the graph data in a file, then let Graphviz output layout information in the dot-format: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html#d:xdot1.4 
Parse the output file and then redraw the graphs on screen.

Comment: Thank you for that purpose. What I want is more along the lines to make a graph editor. A progressive construction

Comment: Updated the answer. Consider asking your question on the Racket mailing list. Chances are someone has written a graph editor - or the start of one - already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. You must have the dot program installed.

```
#lang racket
(require graph)
(require racket/gui/base)

(define dot-command "/usr/local/bin/dot -Tpng ~a >~a")

;; Given a graph, use dot to create a png and return the path to the png
(define (make-graphviz-png g)
  (let ([dot-string (graphviz g #:colors (coloring/brelaz g))]
        [dot-file (make-temporary-file "example~a.dot")]
        [png-file (make-temporary-file "example~a.png")])

    (display-to-file dot-string dot-file #:exists 'replace)
    (system (format dot-command dot-file png-file))
    png-file))

;; The graph
(define test-graph (unweighted-graph/directed '((hello world))))

;; Generate the png from the graph
(define bitmap (read-bitmap (make-graphviz-png test-graph)))

;; Display in a frame -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355251/bitmap-in-dr-racket
(define f (new frame% [label "Your Graph"]))
(new message% [parent f] [label bitmap])
(send f show #t)
```

Comment: You can avoid having to deal with temporary files, by wrapping the system call in `(with-output-to-string (lambda () (with-input-from-string dot-string (lambda () ... ))))`. We do so in https://github.com/fractalide/fractalide/blob/fe5c9d03443e8291b90ccbf1cdf8bf20ced9d233/modules/rkt/rkt-fbp/agents/hyperflow/graph/loader.rkt#L47 when we ask `dot` to layout our nodes for our graph editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [graphviz](https://docs.racket-lang.org/graphviz/index.html) package. If you want to use the dot language directly, you can use the dot->pict function. Alternatively, you can use digraph->pict, which makes dot a bit more powerful by allowing using Racket picts as node shapes.